# Java streaming higher order function

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to process an object that has nested lists 2 levels deep. For example my object can be broken down to something like this:

```
TopLevel: [
    MidLevel: [
        LowLevel,
        LowLevel,
        .
        .
    ],
    MidLevel: [
        LowLevel,
        LowLevel,
        .
        .
    ]
    .
    .
]
```

Essentially `TopLevel` contains a list of `MidLevel` objects, which in turn each contain a list of `LowLevel` objects. At the end of the processing I would like to build `SomeObj` for each of the `LowLevel` objects. However `SomeObj` requires information from `TopLevel`, `MidLevel`, and `LowLevel`.

I have been trying to write code in a more functional style over the last several months so my first thought was to create a higher order function that I could build up over each level in the object. The function looks like this:

```
Function<MidLevel, Function<LowLevel, SomeObj>> buildObjects(TopLevel topLevel) {
    return midLevel ->
        lowLevel -> {
            return buildSomeObj(topLevel, midLevel, lowLevel);
        };
}
```

I intend to use this function in some way like the following (assume I have utility functions that provide a stream of the lists):

```
Function<MidLevel, Function<LowLevel, SomeObj>> topBuilder = buildObjects(topLevel);
List<SomeObj> objs = topLevel.streamMid()
    .map(topBuilder)
    .streamLow()
    .map(Function::apply)
    .collect(/*collect to list*/);
```

However, this obviously does not work because once I apply the `MidLevel` objects to the `topBuilder` function my stream is now a stream of functions and not `MidLevel` objects, thus I do not have access to the list of `LowLevel` objects in the stream anymore.

Is there any solution to this or am I trying to solve this functionally when it's not well suited to it? Is there a way to both apply the function, and also have access to the original object that was applied to that function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`flatMap()` and nesting are the way to go. Try this:

```
topLevelStream() //create a stream of top level elements
  .flatMap( top -> top.streamMid() //create a stream of mid level elements
    .flatMap( mid -> mid.streamLow() //create a stream of low level elements
      .map(low -> "use top, mid and low here") 
    ) 
  )
  .collect( ... );
```

By nesting like this you still have access to the elements in the outer functions and the combination of `flatMap()` and `map()` exposes the stream that `map()` is called upon to `collect()`.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, there is no top-level stream as such, hence a single `flatMap` shall do that.

Comment: @Naman you're right, though adapting that shouldn't be a huge problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `flatMap` as:

```
List<SomeObj> objs = topLevel.getMidLevels().stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getLowLevels().stream().map(b -> topBuilder.apply(a).apply(b)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with your entities analogous to:

```
class TopLevel {
    List<MidLevel> midLevels;
}

class MidLevel {
    List<LowLevel> lowLevels;
}

class LowLevel {
}

class SomeObj {
}
```

Comment: Aside: Your `buildObjects` implementation can look much better as `return midLevel -> lowLevel -> buildSomeObj(topLevel, midLevel, lowLevel)`